# facebook link to join users

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

Is there a way to create a link like www.facebook.com/wallpapers.3d in order the user to click and be redirected to the facebook group? I can only use the link from groups which is like http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=315018914695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not programming related, but the answer is no. Only pages, applications, and users can have nice URLs, not groups.